# Semantics of #just[x]things

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, word-usage, semantics

I've recently had [a heated discussion](http://web.archive.org/web/20181025221705/https://share.jodel.com/post?postId=5bd16a5e783429f9e650a158&_branch_match_id=583888458946431442) in German with another person over the use and semantics of the hashtag **#just[x]things** – this happened on an anonymous location-based German social network called Jodel. For the sake of simplicity, let's just call them Bob. I'm not a native speaker, and presumably so, neither is Bob.

The context is a post on something that happened in my hometown of Duisburg to which I replied "#justduisburgthings". Bob complained that the use of the hashtag is inappropriate and held up the opinion that the implied meaning is that such things would *only* ever happen there. My understanding is that the implied meaning is that such a story is *typical for, but not exclusive to* the city.

Google didn't turn up any sources that could be used to prove or disprove either side (maybe I'm just too bad at using Google), and since I'm curious to find out whether I might be mistaken after all, I've decided to take this question to EL&U.

Comment: I've only noticed just now that the web link doesn't show the full discussion, some of the comments which are visible in the app are missing, in case anyone was wondering why the discussion seems a bit one-sided...

Comment: I mean, in some sense, you’re both right. #JustNerdThings would describe something that is *typical* of nerds, but there is some kind of exclusivity to it, in that *that is why you’d choose to claim it*. If it applied to everyone, then it wouldn’t differentiate nerds (in my example). Like #JustGirlThings is usually applied to ... girly things. Sure, men could do them, but you’re IGing or tweeting about them *because* they highlight how girls are different. So #JustDuisburgThings should be applied to things that *characterize* your town.

Comment: Typically, people would say "only in [Duisburg]" to describe things that couldn't happen elsewhere. That's not to say that using "just" is unambiguous.

Comment: *Just* has at least two distinctly different meanings in this context. 1) Things that could *only* apply to X; or 2) It is *merely* something that applies to X (i.e. -- no big deal, it's to be expected, considering it's X we're talking about). I happen to think attempting to dictate usage of words in language not one's own, when the way it was used is * technically correct* regardless, is awfully rude. I don't know the common usage of this hashtag, but I would have simply ignored the grammar police.

Comment: I don't see this as a POB.

Answer (score 0):

Your disagreement centers on the various meanings of the adverb *[just](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/just)*: one sense meaning ‘only,’ the other ‘simply’:

> 14.04.2016 It’s [*just a Philadelphia thing*](http://www.philly.com/philly/columnists/john_smallwood/20160415_Prep_Charter_s_Kahleah_Copper_drafted_7th_in_WNBA_by_Washington.html). Whenever a local player is drafted in a professional sport, the question of how playing in the City of Brotherly Love helped prepare them seems to always come up. — Philly.com
>
> 06.02.2008 I definitely see Philadelphia being a heavy Obama city — it's [*just a Philadelphia thing*](http://www.talkleft.com/story/2008/2/6/94631/73045/elections2008/After-Super-Tuesday). — After Super Tuesday - TalkLeft: The Politics Of Crime

Wondering about the role the city played in an athlete’s early career and voting heavily Democratic are simply the way things are in Philadelphia. While the adverb doesn’t specifically mean ‘typically’, the result is basically identical: if something in a particular city weren’t typical or expected, it wouldn’t be *simply* so.

*Just* can also mean ‘only’:

> I'm curious — do other Italian neighborhoods in places like Boston, Chicago and New York do slow roasted pork sandwiches comparable to Tommy Dinic's or is that [*just a Philadelphia thing*](https://forums.egullet.org/topic/76174-hoagies-cheesesteaks-pork-italiano/?page=12)? — Forum post, egullet.org

And in the negative, *just* can only mean ‘only’:

> 23.05.2011 Homelessness is [*not just a Philadelphia thing*](https://www.phillymag.com/news/2011/05/23/frank-diciccos-heartless-response-to-homelessness/). It's a national thing, actually a national disgrace in light of the abundant wealth that this country displays when it really wants to. — PhillyMag.com

So you’re both right, but you may have noticed that the expression is more often couched in the singular.

Comment: Of  course, it is about *only*; but no, this is not it.

Comment: @Kris: What is the “it” that this is not?

Answer (score -1):

Bob obviously means that the *just* qualifies **[x]**:

> Things, exclusive to Duisburg.

and not **[x]things** which you presumed:

> Things, about Duisburg, and nothing else.